# Translation of “would have + infinitive” into French

Tags: traduction, anglais, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

I know that *"have to"* in English, as in *"I have to do it"* (expression of obligation), should be translated using the verb *"devoir"*. So *"I have to do it"* would be *"Je dois le faire"*.

In the same vein, I'd expect *"I **would** have to do it"* to be translated as:
*"Je **devrais** le faire"* (Using the conditional: *would* + *have to* = *would* + *devoir*). But in an online French course I saw this sentence being translated as: **J'aurais à le faire.**

This seems to be wrong to me, and not conveying the intended meaning of obligation. So what is the correct way to translate *would have to + any infinitive*?

Peut-on produire des sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Avoir à* et *devoir* s'emploient tous les deux pour exprimer l'obligation. Cependant j'y mettrais une nuance.

**Avoir à :**
Obligation qu'on s'impose à soi-même et la notion de devoir est plus ou moins contraignante selon le verbe qui suit.
« Je ne peux pas aller au cinéma ce soir, j'ai du ménage à faire. » (Le ménage ce n'est pas vital, je m'impose moi-même la contrainte)

Exemple donné dans le [TFL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) :

> J'**ai** maintenant **à** vous expliquer pourquoi je vous écris de Tours et
>   non de Tocqueville où je devrais et voudrais être. Tocqueville *Correspondance* [avec Gobineau], 1853, p. 200.

**Devoir :**
Obligation en général imposée par une contrainte extérieure :  morale, loi, règlement, etc...
« Je ne peux pas aller au cinéma ce soir, je dois garder les 10 euros qui me restent pour acheter à manger à mes enfants. » (Moralement j'y suis obligé).

Ceci dit ça dépend du contexte et je ne vois pas de grande différence entre  :

« J'aurais à changer de voiture, je n'en aurais pas les moyens. »
et
« Je devrais changer de voiture, je n'en aurais pas les moyens. »

---

Both, *avoir à* and *devoir* express obligation. With a nuance.
**Avoir à** is an obligation one brings upon themselves. (In English you'd use "have to")

Devoir is more of a moral obligation that is brought on to you by the outside world, a set of rules imposed by the workplace, the law, etc...(In English you'd use "must" rather than "have to").

Comment: « Avoir quelque chose à faire » et « avoir à faire quelque chose » me semblent avoir des sens fort différents, je ne suis donc pas convaincu de la pertinence de l’exemple du ménage. Cela dit, je ne suis pas convaincu par l’argument de manière générale.

Comment: @Édouard J'ai à faire du ménage (ou j'ai du ménage à faire, la place du complément est dans ce cas indifférente) exprime une idée d'obligation tout comme je dois faire du ménage.

Comment: @Édouard: Le Petit Robert est d'accord avec moi : *Avoir à : être dans l'obligation de. V. Devoir.* et un des exemples : *avoir des lettres à écrire*.

Comment: Ce n’était vraiment pas clair : l’argument avec lequel je ne suis pas d’accord, c’est donner la nuance « contrainte personnelle » à « avoir à ». Pour ce qui est du placement du complément, je ne suis décidément pas d’accord. J’nterprète « J’ai du ménage à faire » comme « J’ai du ménage qui doit être fait » (il est tout à fait possible — et, dans mon cas, probable, j’ai un ménage monstre à faire dans mon bureau depuis des années — que je le laisse traîner) et « J’ai à faire du ménage » comme « Je dois faire du ménage » (je suis dans l’obligation ou la nécessité de le faire).

Answer (score 2):

That's because *devoir* in the conditional translates to *should*.

*J'aurais à* is one of several formulations you can use. *Je serais obligé de* and *je serais forcé de* are also possible.